# Getting An item with the same key has already been added Error when mapping model

Tags: c#, serialization, model

```
"Types": [
            {
                "activeFlag": true,
                "Type": "Out"
            },
            {
                "activeFlag": true,
                "Type": "Today"
            },
            {
                "activeFlag": true,
                "Type": "Later"
            },
            {
                "activeFlag": true,
                "Type": "Now"
            },
            {
                "activeFlag": true,
                "Type": "Example"
            },
            {
                "activeFlag": true,
                "Type": "Hour"
            },
            {
                "activeFlag": true,
                "Type": "In"
            }
        ],
```

I have that above json structure I am trying to map it into my model like so it has multiple activeFlag attributes.

```
public class Info
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Types { get; set; }

}


...Types = new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        { "activeFlag", "true" },
                        { "Type", "Out" },
                        { "activeFlag", "true" },
                        { "Type", "Today" },
                        { "activeFlag", "true" },
                        { "Type", "Later" },
                        { "activeFlag", "true" },
                        { "Type", "Now" }...
                    }...
```

The following code gives out `An item with the same key has already been added`  How can i map it properly?

Comment: In a dictionary, the key values need to be unique, you are adding `activeFlag` multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a dictionary, the key values need to be unique, you are adding `activeFlag` multiple times. A better way to achieve this would be to use a class that holds the properties you need. For example:

```
public class Item
{
    public bool ActiveFlag { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

And make you base object a list of this class:

```
public class Info
{
    public List<Item> Types { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can deserialise properly.

Comment: Ah, Yes Not sure why I am trying to use Dictonary here, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The key of a dictionary need to be unique, you can use a tuple like this
`List<Tuple<string,string>>` or this `List<(string,string)>`

Comment: This will work with Newtonsoft but not with the new `System.Text.Json` objects (at least not without a bunch of fiddling)